# fail to use variable from python panda sending Gmail

Tags: python, pandas, gmail

I am layman for python.
I want to write a code for sending email under certain condition that "Name" which is VIP in my data set
The data set and filter worked fine, and function of sending email also worked
but I don't know how to apply the variable e = email which associate with the value VIP=Yes
and i = Name which associate with VIP value = Yes.
I try to send a email to specific address by filling the name by variable i. but it became attachment with "no name". Can anyone help? Many Many thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
df = pd.read_excel('s1.xlsx')
print('RAW_DATA')
print(df)
print('========================================')
df1 = df.loc[df.VIP.str.startswith('Y')]  #'Sowing the name associted with VIP by the vaule Y'
df0 = df.loc[df.VIP.str.startswith('N')]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=['Name','VIP','Email']) #display the information that relate to 'df1'
df00 = pd.DataFrame(df0, columns=['Name','VIP','Email'])
print('VIP LIST')
print (df2)
print('========================================')
print('Non-VIP LIST')
print (df00)
print('========================================')

content = MIMEMultipart()  
content["subject"] = "Learn Code With Mike" 
content["from"] = "*****@gmail.com"  #send from
for e in df2.Email:
    content["to"] = e # receiver
content.attach(MIMEText(i,"Demo python send email")) #content

import smtplib
with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port="587") as smtp:  
    try:
        smtp.ehlo()  # 
        smtp.starttls()  # 
        smtp.login("*****.com", "******")  # 
        smtp.send_message(content)  # 
            print("Complete!")
        except Exception as s:
            print("Error message: ", s)
```

---

```
Output 
RAW_DATA
    Name  VIP  Age                  Email
0  Felix  YES   32        felix123@gmail.com
1  Chris   NO   17        fehf7@gmail.com
2    Tom  YES   26          e@hotmail.com
3  Dover  YES   34     dover234@gmail.com
4    Tim  YES   32        t67@hotmail.com
5   Wing   NO   42       997ui4@gmail.com
6  Peter   NO   35        p2656@gmail.com
7  Brown  YES   24    brown3442@gmail.com
8   Fung  YES   54   fung275636@gmail.com
9   Ryan   NO   37     ryan6726@gmail.com
========================================
VIP LIST
    Name  VIP                  Email
0  Felix  YES     felix123@gmail.com
2    Tom  YES          e@hotmail.com
3  Dover  YES     dover234@gmail.com
4    Tim  YES        t67@hotmail.com
7  Brown  YES    brown3442@gmail.com
8   Fung  YES   fung275636@gmail.com
========================================
Non-VIP LIST
    Name VIP               Email
1  Chris  NO     fehf7@gmail.com
5   Wing  NO    997ui4@gmail.com
6  Peter  NO     p2656@gmail.com
9   Ryan  NO  ryan6726@gmail.com
========================================

output of i =
felix123@gmail.com
e@hotmail.com
dover234@gmail.com
t67@hotmail.com
brown3442@gmail.com
fung275636@gmail.com
```

Comment: I try for 
e in df2.Email:
    content["to"] = [e]''' 
but it show the error that Error message:  sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 import smtplib
 for name, vip_state, e in df2.values:
    content["to"] = e # receiver
    # name contains the name of the receiver
    content.attach(MIMEText(name,"Demo python send email")) #content
    
    
    with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port="587") as smtp:  
        try:
            smtp.ehlo()  # 
            smtp.starttls()  # 
            smtp.login("*****.com", "******")  # 
            smtp.send_message(content)  # 
                print("Complete!")
            except Exception as s:
                print("Error message: ", s)
```

Comment: it shows, "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)"

Comment: It seem to be work to covert to a string but it become "felix123@gmail.come@hotmail.comdover234@gmail.comt67@hotmail.combrown3442@gmail.comfung275636@gmail.comfelix6772121@gmail.com"

Comment: I don't exactly understand what do you want to do with emails and names then.

Comment: I want to send a email by for each "Name" by the condition VIP=YES from the dataset

Comment: I modified my message, if you want a different name per email, you then need to iterate over email adresses, sand their name as attachment and send a mail each time

Comment: it is seem not work.. does it relate to the problem of formatting? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You might need to provide more information on your latest issue or I can just guess what's encountered.

Do you use personal google account to login?
Because from **May 30, 2022**, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps which uses only your username and password, so you may not able to use it now.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en&utm_source=google-account&utm_medium=profile-less-secure-apps-card

If you use other smtp server, then maybe give it some time to finish login process:

```py
 import smtplib, time
 for name, vip_state, e in df2.values:
    content["to"] = e # receiver
    # name contains the name of the receiver
    content.attach(MIMEText(name,"Demo python send email")) #content
    
    with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port="587") as smtp:  
        try:
            smtp.ehlo()
            smtp.starttls()
            time.sleep(1) # <-
            smtp.login("*****.com", "******")
            smtp.send_message(content)
                print("Complete!")
            except Exception as s:
                print("Error message: ", s)
```